# Laravel 5 - Where should I write this function, and how?

Tags: php, laravel, view, model, controller

Goodevening,

I have an overview page where I display all my project items.

I have a model (Project.php) a controller (ProjectController) where I send the variable *$project* (this includes all the information for each project) to the specific view.

Note: Each project has a own row in the database. (Quit obvious I guess)

Now I also have a table 'tasks' related to a specific project. In my view I wanna display how much of the total tasks are 'done'. (This is doing with the column 'done' (true/false, boolean)).

Now because I have a foreach function in my view (to display each individuele project) I can make the function in the view. But the Laravel framework is there for reasons. And writing out a lot of php in a view isn't the right way.

But, where should I make this function? And how can I use it in my foreach (in the view). Ofcourse I can make a new foreach in my model or controller and send that variable to my view. But then I can't use that one in my view-foreach as things will get mixed up.

I don't know how/where I can set up a function like this on a clean way.

Kinds regards,

Dylan

Comment: any example code ?

Comment: yes give us some code please ^^  at the moment, there is no way to know exactly if you are close... or nowhere near of what you want to achieve

Comment: As mentioned before, without code it is difficult to answer. But do you have relationships set up? Because normally you would access `tasks` via relationship from `projects` in your views....

Comment: There are many tools for achieving this: blade directives, view composers, helper functions you may write, model presenters, etc. It wil definitely help a lot if you post your view with this function written "the wrong way" (though, I prefer to think that you just prefer an alternative), so we can build from there one or more refactored approaches for a better architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in app directory(forexample app/Helpers/), or wherever you want and name it yourHelperFunction.php.

After creating that file, Laravel won’t recognize the file until it is registered inside composer.json file. Add files array inside autoload section.

```
.
.
.
"autoload": {
   "files":[
     "app/Helpers/yourHelperFunction.php"
   ]
}
.
.
.
```

then do composer dump autoload and you are ready to use the function inside the blade

Answer (score 0):

Use Blade engine, not Core PHP loops.
It is wise to use blade engine then core php codes.

You can see the documentation
[Laravel 5 Blade Template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I've figured it out (I guess?).

I have this function in my Project Model.

```
    public function getTaskDonePercentage($id) {
    $tasks = Task::where('project_id', $id)->count();

    $tasks_done = Task::where([
      ['project_id', $id],
      ['status', 'done']
    ])->count();

    if ($tasks_done > 0) {
      $calc = ($tasks_done / $tasks) * 100;
    }
    else {
      $calc = '100';
    }

    return round($calc) . '%';
  }
```

Then in my view I just call the function in the foreach like:

```
@foreach
{{ $project_item->getTaskDonePercentage($project_item->id) }}
@endforeach
```

Tbh I still wanna know if this approach is a good one. (Or, if not, why it isnt?).

Thanks!